# Can light cool down materials?

Tags: photons, scattering, phonons

I was studying [Raman scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_scattering#Stokes_and_anti-Stokes) and I computed the probability of anti-Stokes scattering (with density of states n, at the numerator) over Stokes (n+1 at denominator). The densities are based on the Bose-Einstein distribution because we are talking about phonons on a crystal.

At nearly 1000 K of temperature the probability of the two events are the same, as we see in the plot (fraction value = 0.5). The curve seems to have a raising behaviour after 1000 K, meaning that anti-Stokes effects are more probable over Stokes' ones.

Anti-Stokes scattering gives us back from the material a photon with higher frequency, thus, higher energy, at cost of a phonon (or more) being absorbed from the crystal lattice. Absorbing a phonon diminishes the "amount of movement" of the crystal atoms, decreasing their thermal velocities that, at over 1000 K is still pretty high. With some [SERS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-enhanced_Raman_spectroscopy) effect, the intensity of the phenomenon could be large.

Does that mean that, under specific selection conditions, light is cooling down the material?

[image: anti-Stokes/Stokes efficiencies]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific Raman-scattering process you mention will not have a cooling effect. At high temperatures, the two cross-section will even out (i.e. the relative weight will asymptotically approach $1/2$ from below) and it will not produce any cooling.

On the other hand, it's perfectly possible to use specially-engineered states of light (typically laser light) to cool down matter; this is generally known as [**laser cooling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling), and nowadays there's a significant array of different ways to achieve it.

Among those ways there *is* what's known as [Raman sideband cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_cooling), but that requires you to specifically pump on the lower Raman sideband (*without* pumping the upper band, in contrast to your method) such that a portion of the Raman fluorescence will go on the upper sideband, which will remove energy from the material.